# MongoDB pipeline unwind and check for empty array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm unwinding one field which is an array of date objects, however in some cases there are empty array's which is fine. I'd like the same treatment using a pipeline, but in some cases, I want to filter the results which have an empty array.

```
pipeline = []
pipeline.append({"$unwind": "$date_object"})
pipeline.append({"$sort": {"date_object" : 1}})
```

I want to use the pipeline format, however the following code does not return any records:

```
pipeline.append({"$match": {"date_object": {'$exists': False }}})
```

nor does the following work:

```
pipeline.append({"$match": {"date_object": []}})
```

and then:

```
results = mongo.db.xxxx.aggregate(pipeline)
```

I'm also trying:

```
pipeline.append({ "$cond" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$date_object", [] ] }, [ { '$value' : 0 } ], '$date_object' ] } )
```

But with this I get the following error:

```
.$cmd failed: exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$cond'
```

However if I query using find such as `find({"date_object": []})`, I can get these results. How can I make this work with the pipeline.

Comment: To get empty array document, try to match `{"$date_object.1": {'$exists': true }}` before `$unwind`. BTW, when you call `find`, it matches with empty arrays, but when you `$unwind`, it tries create for each entry new document. As you have empty array, no document is created.

Comment: @Valijon Is there a way after the unwind, so I can keep my existing structures?

Comment: I think so. I am trying query...

Comment: What are you trying to do? perhaps there is a better way to do this without using `$unwind`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done in MongoDB shell, but it can be translated into Python easily in python language.

Is it your requirements?

I suppose you have such structure:

```
db.collection.save({foo:1, date_object:[new Date(), new Date(2016,1,01,1,0,0,0)]})
db.collection.save({foo:2, date_object:[new Date(2016,0,16,1,0,0,0),new Date(2016,0,5,1,0,0,0)]})
db.collection.save({foo:3, date_object:[]})
db.collection.save({foo:4, date_object:[new Date(2016,1,05,1,0,0,0), new Date(2016,1,06,1,0,0,0)]})
db.collection.save({foo:5, date_object:[]})

// Get empty arrays after unwind
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{_id:"$_id", foo:"$foo", 
        date_object:{
            $cond: [ {"$eq": [{ $size:"$date_object" }, 0]}, [null], "$date_object" ]
        }
      }
    },
    {$unwind:"$date_object"},
    {$match:{"date_object":null}}
])

// Get empty arrays before unwind
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{"date_object.1":{$exists:false}}},
    {$project:{_id:"$_id", foo:"$foo", 
        date_object:{
            $cond: [ {"$eq": [{ $size:"$date_object" }, 0]}, [null], "$date_object" ]
        }
      }
    },
    {$unwind:"$date_object"}
])
```

> Only empty date_object

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56eb0bd618d4d09d4b51087a"),
        "foo" : 3,
        "date_object" : null
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56eb0bd618d4d09d4b51087c"),
        "foo" : 5,
        "date_object" : null
    }
]
```

At the end, if you need only empty date_object, you don't need to aggregate, you can easely achieve it with `find`:

```
db.collection.find({"date_object.1":{$exists:false}},{date_object:0})
```

> Output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56eb0bd618d4d09d4b51087a"),
    "foo" : 3
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56eb0bd618d4d09d4b51087c"),
    "foo" : 5
}
```

Comment: Does this match just the empty [] dates?

Comment: It matches both. If you need to match only empty dates, you can use `$match` as first step (commented ) or add other step un the end with `$match` where date_object is null. Why do you need to unwind only empty date_object?

Comment: I tried the $match as above with the $date_object.1, but this failed, before the unwind.

Comment: I tried something similar to your recommendation, but this fails too.